# "Космическая опера" — происхождение

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошла традиция называть эпические фантастические произведения "космическими операми"? Почему именно операми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот как раз для эпичности. "Опера" именно так и воспринимается. Длинно и непонятно ))).
Аналогично "мыльные оперы". Правда с ними своя история. "Мыльные" - от рекламы мыла, которая постоянно шла во время показа первого такого "сериала". Фирма-производитель спонсировала производство и по "праву первой ночи" оптом закупила рекламное время. Но это именно про "мыльная", само название "опера" не связано с этой историей. Хотя в сети можно найти и утверждения о том, что это была реклама именно во время показа оперы, но я лично очень крепко в том сомневаюсь, оперы по ящику не показывают, тем более - в таком количестве.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "космическая опера" возникло под влиянием двух других выражений: "лошадиная опера" - фильм или театральная постановка об американском Западе, вестерн, и "мыльная опера" - сентиментальный фильм (часто телесериал), посвященный проблемам любви, семейных отношений, воспитания детей. Выражение "космическая опера" использовалось в значении "насыщенный действием рассказ о космических приключениях".

Answer (score 0):

"Опера" - от насыщенности событиями. Мыльные оперы - это сплошные интриги, измены, роковые встречи и т.п. Космические оперы, видимо, по аналогии.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "опера" родственно слову "opus". Правда, с русском языке эта связь не чувствуется. Но, наверное, название возникло не в русском?